# Tool for testing JPA queries

Tags: java, jpa, jpql

I'm developing a application using JPA(Eclipselink) and it works better than expected. However I have found it a bit tricky to write the JPQL queries and has searched for a tool to write and test the queries, but havn't really found any. Does anyone have any suggestion on tools for this or other tips?

The tool can be stand alone or a eclipse plugin.

Answer (score 2):

You could use standard JUnit tests to perform your JPQL queries against a demo database and compare the results with a custom built set - although that it is necessary, that you build a database instance on the fly or create an own testing database instance.

Comment: Agreed, unit tests are quite an easy way to quickly test out such things. Slapping an in-memory pure Java database in there such as HSQL or H2 makes the process of playing with JPA almost painless.

Comment: this seems promising, do you know any good tutorials to check out in order to get started?